# Rake assets:precompile

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows, postgresql, phpmyadmin

```
C:\Sites\dtr-payroll>rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.4, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3. Using bundle exec may solve this.
C:/Sites/dtr-payroll/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/dtr-payroll/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/dtr-payroll/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Have you run with `bundle exec`? Doing so should ensure you are invoking the correct version of `rake`, (i.e., try `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`)

Comment: Try with remove the file Gemfile.lock and run bundle install command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your rake to 10.0.4 via

```
bundle update rake
```

that would fix it

Answer (score 19):

you should first delete your `Gemfile.lock` file and `bundle install` again and then use

```
rake assets:precompile
```

this is because you have activated rake 10.0.4 but in your Gemfile.lock file it is rake 10.0.3 so either you changed it or delete Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: Adding to this, if you would prefer not to delete your `Gemfile.lock` file, you should be able to just run `bundle update rake` to update the rake version used by your application.

Answer (score 2):

please try

> bundle exec rake assets:precompile

you should google it first

Comment: This does work but I would prefer to follow Nicks aproach and update rake inside your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bundle exec rake assets:precompile
if you update the database migrate,you can use:
bundle exec rake db:migrate